# Create a function that checks if a checkbox is checked and print a line when selected

Tags: javascript

I am doing a homework assignment that requires me to create a function named "MultipleBP" in JavaScript that checks to see if a check box is checked, and if it is, it should print a line in another element if it is.This is what i found so far. I'm sure there's something wrong with it. I need it to print to a text box with the id "notes".

```
    function multipleBP() {
if (document.getElementById('multiple').checked) {
    document.getElementById("notes").value="checked";
   }else{
    document.getElementById("notes").value="not checked";
  }
```

}

Comment: `if (mult.checked){...`

Comment: how do I get the checkbox when checked to print to a texbox

Answer (score 1):

The code assigns the element to `mult` but evaluates the `checked` property on `multiple` instead of `mult`.

Once you have the conditional working lets work through setting the value in a textbox.  By a textbox I assume you mean an `input`.

So the first thing you must do is retrieve the input from the DOM.  You have already illustrated you can do this, you retrieved `multi` from the DOM.  The next thing you must do is set the `value` of the textbox to whatever content you need.  Look at the properties on an [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) select the appropriate one and assign the value to it.

Comment: how do I get the checkbox when checked to print to a texbox

Comment: @user3308486 What do you want to print to the textbox?

Comment: the assignment says it has to print the text "Description of Project area"

Comment: @user3308486 I gave you some insights into how to accomplish the final piece.  This is homework so I'm not going to provide a complete answer.

Comment: The element that I am writing to has the id "notes"

Comment: Ok, so how do you get an element from the DOM when you have an id?

Comment: Im not sure but maybe its getElementId

Comment: @user3308486 Exactly, so grab the element with `getElementById` before the `if` statement, now how do you set the value of the input element you retrieved.

Comment: Im going to have to look at other examples cause I can't think of anything at this time

Comment: The textbox element's actual tag is input, inputs have a property `value` which can be set like `input.value = "your text here";`

Comment: i can't get the conditional statements to work. the value dosn't change when I select the element

Comment: Is the id `mult` or `multiple` originally it was `mult`

Comment: the variable is mult and the id is multiple